# getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id....) возвращает null

Tags: java, android

Есть две кнопки. По нажатию первой кнопки добавляется динамически фрагмент с помощью `BeginTransaction()`. При нажатии на вторую кнопку находится `TextView` с помощью `getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(id...).getView()...`, и меняется текст. Факт в том, что это работает. Но если объединить оба действия в одной кнопке, то фрагмент не находится, и вернётся `null` в `getFragmentManager().getFragmentById(id...).getView()`.

Есть ли какие-нибудь подводные камни, которые могут быть причиной такого поведения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию (и это рекомендуемое и правильное поведение) все транзакции с фрагментами происходят асинхронно. Засим после вызова `commit` у транзакции добавления фрагмента он не добавляется мгновенно и при попытке обращения к нему его ещё не будет в стэке активити в активированном состоянии.

Вам надо переделать логику изменения текста в фрагменте с учётом этого поведения. В принципе пытаться трогать разметку фрагмента напрямую - плохая практика.

В зависимости от того зачем вам менять текст во фрагменте можно идти разными путями.

1. Если вам надо просто задать начальный текст для фрагмента единожды - передавайте данные во фрагмент при его создании через `Fragment#setArguments(Bundle args)` с последующим вытаскиванием оных во фрагменте в методе `onCreate` через `Fragment#getArguments()` и устанавливайте текст в `TextView` в методе `onCreateView` фрагмента.
2. Если вам надо менять что-то по нажатию на кнопку, например, или по к-л другому событию, то вам надо создать во фрагменте метод, который будет изменять текст в текстовом поле и вызывать этот метод из активити, получив фрагмент из `FragmentManager`-а, проверив, что фрагмент в активном состоянии (`Fragment#isAdded() == true`), чтобы не нарваться на ситуации его открепления от активити.

---

<s>Если хочется прямо совсем одну за другой вызывать строки и ожидать, что фрагмент будет добавлен синхронно и к его разметке можно сразу обращаться, то можно попробовать вместо `commit()` у транзакции добавления фрагмента вызвать `commitNow()`. В теории, это даст нужный эффект. Но никто этого точно не знает, т.к. делать так - очень плохо и неправильно и засим так никто не делает, так что может это и не сработает.</s>

Answer (score 0):

Как тупо. Я бы мог и удалить этот запрос,  но все же вдруг кому то понадобится. Вообщем. После того как добавили фрагмент и сделали commit(), как я понял, нужно" чтобы код вернулся к активити"(отрежьте мне язык), поэтому создаёте поток и запускайте его. В потоке создайте сообщение и отправьте его handler'у активити. В хендлере при нужном  в сообщении выполнитея по изменению текста. Все. 
Ps не минусьте пожалуйста, я много не понимаю, и к такому решению на проблем пришел методом экспериментов. И ещё раз повторюсь, не удаляю потому что может пригодится кому то. Если не поймет какой бред у меня написан, то хотябы точно поймет как действовать дальше.

Comment: Да, вы верно подозреваете, что это неверный подход. См. мой ответ.